# How to Pass Parameters to Http Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Hey guys I created some cloud functions that use the onCall method to create endpoints that I was originally calling with the httpsCallable functions in my reactjs app. But, I need to set up cron jobs to keep calling my cloud functions to keep them "warm" so I think I need to make the functions using onRequest instead to make them http calls. So I am able to call these with the axios plugin in react but how do I pass parameters to a function? For instance if I have a function:

```
exports.testCall = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.????????);
}
```

How do I extract the passed values from the request and how do I send them? Right now I am calling the "testCall" endpoint using axios.get("generated_url", {test: "test"}). But I am not able to console.log "test". How do I pass an object to my cloud function and then extract that data?

Thanks.

Comment: You really can't keep a cloud function perfectly "warm".  At some point, server instances will come and go over time.  You can't prevent that from happening.  You can *maybe* make a cold start less apparent, but you can't eliminated it.

Comment: Ya sorry I should have specified, I am just trying to make them warm more often. There is still a lot of cases where the functions could be cold. Any idea on how I can pass parameters to my cloud functions?